# Div Slide not working properly in Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery

I need help solving this problem, I'm creating a social media slider, simple click to revel social media icons and click to hide, which has has a slide out to revel and slide in to hide, and it works perfectly and as expected in Firefox and IE but Chrome/Safari give it a weird effect where it slide up wards instead out from the right to the left, here is my a sample on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R3AZM/

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:table` to `div#open` and `div#close`, and remove width from `#social-holder`

http://jsfiddle.net/bikerabhinav/R3AZM/3/

Also, use `.animate()` for a cleaner effect.